# How Path forwarding in Google Domains works?

Tags: dns, redirection

I just registered a domain name in Google Domains and when doing initial setup I noticed it had a `path forwarding` option, with the following explanation:

> Path forwarding
>
> For example, if you're forwarding documentationexample.com to
>   example.com, your domain could be forwarded in the following ways:
>
> With path forwarding on: documentationexample.com/about.html redirects
>   to example.com/about.html.
>
> With path forwarding off: documentationexample.com/about.html redirects to example.com.

I wonder how it works in the "path forwarding off" scenario? In my understanding, DNS server can only reply browser's request to translate a domain name to an IP address. The path portion in the URL is not visible to DNS server. How can it tell browser to redirect documentationexample.com/about.html to example.com?

(I tried to contact Google Domains customer support, but failed to submit the question on their web site).

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood the rules. But I think this site is for system admin related questions, isn't it? The trend is that many system admin task have been on cloud, rather than on-premise servers. And the tool chain and knowledge change accordingly. In my opinion, this is just one such question. It's not a question about how to perform a specific set up using vendor specific technology, but how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS does not have a concept of forwarding that is similar to HTTP redirects. Of course there’s CNAMEs and stuff, but they just result in aliases.

Both examples (keeping path or dropping it) from the quoted section are not achievable with DNS alone. They involve a web server (operated by Google) sending HTTP redirects.

Comment: Hi Daniel, but Google Domains is a DNS service provider. It's well known that they don't host website. So do you think how that works? Is it possible that they actually runs a web server for my domain name and redirect to the IP address on which my web server actually runs? I didn't think about this possibility because I thought they just run DNS server.

Comment: Google Domains is an offering by Google which provides just about any digital service imaginable. Even other registrars usually have some minimal web offering for displaying a placeholder page or redirects.

Comment: Sorry it was perhaps my mistake. Google Domains has multiple setting pages, one for DNS and one for HTTP forwarding. I somehow stumbled on the latter one immediately after I successfully bought the service and took it as DNS service provided by Google Domains. If I understand it correctly it's actually a value-added service. I'll talke a closer look and accept your answer later.